# getting the querysting in django's feed class

Tags: django, rss, feed

I want to be able to have an rss feed with an querysting. For example `example.com/rss/bbox?=39.715056,-75.811158,39.5098,-75.491781`

1. I couldn't find any example of rss with querystrings, is this proper?
2. How do I get the arguments using django's [feed class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/syndication/#feed-classes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! the `get_object` method is passed `request` which you then can extract the GET arguments.

```
def get_object(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    bounds = request.GET.get("bbox")
    bbox = _str_to_bbox(bounds)
    ....
    return Obj
```

The returned object can then be used in `items` and most the rest of the feed class's methods